# Creating a contraction with the words "adjustment has"

Tags: contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

Which would be the best way to correct this sentence?

- "An adjustments been
  made to your account."

Is it correct to add an apostrophe ("an adjustment's been made")? Or should the long version be used instead ("an adjustment has been")?

For context, this text will be going into an automated email.

Comment: I would stick to formal English for such a message: "An adjustment has been made to your account."

Comment: In informal speech (whether spoken or transcribed) it would be common to say "An adjustment's been made", but "An adjustment has been made" should be used in formal/official communications.

Comment: And there's always the option of specifying the person or entity that did the adjusting: "X has adjusted your account." This remains a valid option even if you choose to adopt the institutional "we": "We have adjusted your account."

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, if you choose to use a contraction, the apostrophe is **obligatory**, not merely correct.

> An adjustment's been made to your account.

To answer your second question, you should probably use the "long version" anyway.